# FramePositioningControl is null in Blackberry Video player

Tags: video, blackberry, java-me, mmapi

I'm developing a blackberry application that plays video from the server. I've used `Player.start()` and `Player.stop()` for playing and pausing a video. But I also need rewind, forward and seek bar controls in my application. I tried using `FramePositioningControl` for these controls. But the following code is returning `null`:

```
FramePositioningControl framePositioningControl =
        (FramePositioningControl) player.getControl("FramePositioningControl");
```

I searched several forums and they say many players do not support `FramePositioningControl`.  What players support `FramePositioningControl`? And what else should I do to add these controls in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You right, FramePositioningControl returns null at least at specific formats (reproduced on mp4, avi, 3gp)

See also [Java Media Framework - JMF/FOBS4JMF FramePositioningControl Problem](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5370234):

> It's a pretty well known and documented issue that JOBS4JMF doesn't support the FramePositioningControl on a lot of different formats. AVIs, for instance, don't work well, and MPEGs don't work at all.

Maybe you can try to write custom seekable datasource like [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/08/22/experiments-in-streaming-java-me.html) or [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Player-custom-DataSource-streaming-without-RTSP-possible/m-p/322679) (with a difference [RANDOM_ACCESSIBLE](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/media/protocol/SourceStream.html#RANDOM_ACCESSIBLE) in getSeekType() and appropriate seek implementation) but I have no idea how to accomplish this for video...